# H1's are floating into post above in Wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I just noticed that on the Wordpress theme I created the H1 article titles are floating up into the subsequent article when you start to shrink the browser window. I can't seem to find the reason for this. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

```
ul.info li, .excerpt, .post-link {
    float: left;
```

}

The styles above seem to be pushing the title of the article up but if I remove it then "posted by, written on, date" all turn into a horizontal list. Which I don't want.

I don't know if they're related by I noticed when I look at single post pages if I shrink the browser window the content of the article flows off the screen.

Thanks in advance for you help everyone. Really confused.

You can see the problem here: http://www.blog.theplaybook.co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are putting all your articles within a div tag or a section( if in HTML5)

You should use the following CSS for all the article div tags

clear : both

This should solve it.

Comment: That appears to have fixed the issue with the overflowing H1's. Thanks Akshay. : )

Comment: Do you have any idea about why on the single post pages the content of the articles is going off the page when I shrink the window?

Comment: I think its because when you shrink the window the size of each div block also changes and then html drops new stuff in the remaining area, clearing the new articles using a clear ensures that this block is cleared of any floating blocks. Think of it as saying stay away from the floating stuff.
Also if the solution worked for you please vote for it :)